# Find files recursively and rename based on their full path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I'm looking to search for files of a specific name, modify the name to the full path and then copy the results to another folder.

Is it possible to update each find result with the full path as the file name; i.e.

```
./folder/subfolder/my-file.csv
```

becomes

```
folder_subfolder_my-file.csv
```

I am listing the files using the following and would like to script it.

```
find . -name my-file.csv -exec ls {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using bash, you can take advantage of `globstar` and use a `for` loop:

```
shopt -s globstar # set globstar option
for csv in **/my-file.csv; do
  echo "$csv" "${csv//\//_}"
done

shopt -u globstar # unset the option if you don't want it any more
```

With `globstar` enabled, `**` does a recursive search (similar to the basic functionality of `find`).

`"${csv//\//_}"` is an example of `${var//match/replace}`, which does a global replacement of all instances of `match` (here an escaped `/`) with `replace`.

If you're happy with the output, then change the `echo` to `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

With perl's rename command ...

```
$ prename
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]
```

... you can rename multiple files by applying a regular expression. `rename` also accepts file names via stdin:

```
find ... | rename -n 's#/#_#g'
```

Check the results and if they are fine, remove `-n`.

Comment: As usual, probably point out that `rename` is not a standard command, and that there are many implementations with different features, syntax, and behaviors. If at all possible, identify which implementation you are talking about.

Comment: @tripleee True. I think it was preinstalled in my Debian, but it is also possible that it came with some Perl package. The file states it was developed by Robin Barker who took Larry Wall's "eg/rename" from Perl source.

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/bin/rename` should reveal its provenance. It's not part of the Debian base install.

Comment: @tripleee I tried that. I also tried `apt-file search`. No results.

Comment: If it's a symlink, it's probably managed via `update-alternatives`.

Comment: @tripleee Yes it is. `/etc/alternatives/rename -> /usr/bin/prename`. Comes with perl.

Answer (score 0):

Just to demonstrate how to do this with `find`;

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
    for file; do
        f=${file#./}
        cp "$file" "./${f//\//_}"
    done' _ {} +
```

The Bash pattern expansion `${f//x/y}` replaces `x` with `y` throughout. Because `find` prefixes each found file with the path where it was found (here, `./`) we trim that off in order to avoid doing `mv "./file" "._file"`.  And because the slash is used in the parameter expansion itself, we need to backslash the slash we want the shell to interpret literally. Finally, because this parameter expansion syntax is a Bash-only extension, we use `bash` rather than `sh`.

Obviously, if you want to rename rather than copy, replace `cp` with `mv`.

If your `find` does not support `-exec ... +` this needs to be refactored somewhat (probably to use `xargs`); but it should be supported on any reasonably modern platform.